# DBI dbWriteTable

Tags: sql, r

I really like the dbWriteTable function from DBI(I usually use RSQLite or ROracle as backend).

I use that function to import a lot of excel spreadsheets, problem is that if these spreadsheets were created over long term columns change are added/deleted or change name from one document to another.

So my question is does anyone have a relatively quick way to add data to database without having to match filed list perfectly?

Here is sample script that I use

```
require(RSQLite)
require(readxl)

# Create database file
conn <- dbConnect(drv=SQLite(),dbname = "path to database")

# Define import function

excel2sqltable <- function(conn, file, table) {
  source.df <-  read_excel(path=file,col_names = TRUE) %>%
  cbind("SourceFile" = file, .)

  names(source.df) <- source.df %>%
    data.frame(check.names = TRUE) %>%
    {gsub("[.]",x=names(.),replacement="_")}

  print(paste("Importing ", file))

  setOldClass(c("tbl_df", "data.frame"))
  dbWriteTable(conn = conn, name = table, value = source.df, append=TRUE)
}
```

With that function I can do:
   `sapply(list.files(),FUN = function(x){excel2sqltable(conn,x,"Imports")})`

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do here. Are you trying to skip the part about naming `source.df`'s columns? Or are you talking about the `dbWriteTable` part of the script?

Comment: I guess what to upgrade this script to dynamically create fields such that `dbWriteTable` does not raise error `Columns NewColumn not found `.

Comment: Query the db for a single row, and set the column names to match that? I'd have to look in the docs to see if there's a DBI function for just returning column names of a table...

Comment: If you have your tables already in the database, you can get its column names with `cols <- dbListFields(conn, 'Imports')` and then you can actually use those names for your imported data (`source.df`): `source.df <-  read_excel(path=file,col_names = cols, skip = 1)`.

Comment: Right, but when source.df has one extra column lets call it `NewColumn` then `dbWriteTable` will raise error `Columns NewColumn not found`. Consequentially I need to go to the database, and `ALTER TABLE` manually to include `NewColumn` . I want to avoid doing this manually I'd like to automate that part.

Comment: That's because your table is expecting a fixed number of columns. If your file has more columns than the destination table does, then that's a problem you are going to have to resolve by either deleting that column from the data.frame or modifying your table definition.

Comment: @sgp667 - Really reconsider structurally changing databases on the fly. Databases are not spreadsheets designed to be manipulated after design phase especially by application code. The database design step is crucial. Think in advance of **all** columns/types and then align application to adhere to it.

Comment: Agreed but this is a matter of just getting data into database, such that I can clean it up with a data manipulation language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this as a guide:

```
library(RSQLite)

sqlite_conn <- dbConnect(drv = SQLite(),dbname = 'data_dump.sqlite')

excel2sqltable <- function(conn, file, table) {
  source.df <-  readxl::read_excel(path=file,col_names = TRUE) %>%
    cbind("SourceFile" = file, .)

  names(source.df) <- source.df %>%
    data.frame(check.names = TRUE) %>%
    {gsub("[.]",x=names(.),replacement="_")}

  if(!dbExistsTable(conn, table)) {
    dbWriteTable(conn = conn, name = table, value = source.df)
  } else {
    # Get both dataframe columns and table columns
    df_cols <- colnames(source.df)
    tbl_cols <- dbListFields(conn, table)

    # Check if there are columns in the dataframe
    # that are not in the destination table
    # Loop through the missing columns and add
    # them to the database table
    if (length(setdiff(df_cols, tbl_cols)) > 0) {
      missing_cols <- setdiff(df_cols, tbl_cols)
      for (col_name in missing_cols) {
        dbSendStatement(conn, sprintf('ALTER TABLE %s ADD %s VARCHAR', table, col_name))
      }
    }

    setOldClass(c("tbl_df", "data.frame"))


    dbWriteTable(conn = conn, name = table, value = source.df, append=TRUE)
  }
}

lapply(list.files(), function(x) {
  excel2sqltable(sqlite_conn, x, "Imports")
})
dbDisconnect(sqlite_conn)
```

I hope it serves a purpose.